# Design pattern for communication from parent to its derived classes

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, mvvm, parent-child

I extra said derived classes and NOT children classes.

I have a base class and many derived classes. One derived class should call a method on the base class which again is calling a method on each derived class.

How is that possible? What design pattern should I go for implemention a communication

"channel" between my Controllers driving the UI using MVVM design pattern? I know of mediator

pattern but do not like it much as it blurs the borders of an architecture.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean here.  Each instantiated derived class will also be a separate instance of the base class.  They are not separate entities, they are the same thing.  In other words the "base class" will only have one derived class method to call.

Comment: what do you mean by derived class instead of child class?

Comment: Do you mean descendants in some tree of objects, such as the [WPF visual or logical trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a design pattern, but really an understanding of virtual method calls. Let's say I have something:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    protected void DoFoo()
    {
        DoFooInternal();
    }

    protected abstract void DoFooInternal();
}
```

And I have a derived class:

```
public class Bar : Foo
{
    protected override void DoFooInternal()
    {
        // Something here
    }
}
```

In the above example, any call to `DoFoo` on the base class makes a virtual call to the `DoFooInternal` method of the derived class. I could also define my `DoFooInternal` as virtual, if I wanted to provide a baseline implementation:

```
protected virtual void DoFooInternal()
{
   // Baseline implementation here
}
```

In the case of your controllers, this would be the same, you can specify some common shared logic in a `ControllerBase` instance and derive a child controller, e.g. `PeopleController` which can despatch method calls to the base class, which can in turn despatch calls back to virtual methods in the derived class...

Comment: If the OP really wants to be in the context of pure GoF design patterns, the strategy employs virtual methods as you described here to implement its intent

Comment: The Template Method pattern is closely related to this (see my answer below), if we really wanted to shoehorn it into one of the GOFs.  However, your answer is probably more universally useful to the OP. :)

Comment: That fits est also I dont need the base impl. but you gave me good ideas.

Answer (score 1):

For "delegating" responsibility from a superclass to its subclass(es), you might be looking for the [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

It's basically formalizing the concept of using abstract functions (which subclasses must implement, of course) to allow a base class to call a function on its concrete subclass.

Comment: thats not suitable for my needs: "avoid duplication in the code: the general workflow structure is implemented once in the abstract class's algorithm, and necessary variations are implemented in each of the subclasses." I dont have a general workflow in my abstract base class, only implementations in my derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think Command Pattern suits best for your problem. If you scenario is this:

- You have a base class which executes a method(a command) in all derived classes(clients)
- One of the derived class invokes that execution (an invoker)

then the best pattern is Command Pattern.

This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/Command_Pattern.aspx) can give you some idea

But my suggestion is to use interfaces instead of base-derived classes.

Comment: much too complicated stuff for what I need.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Events](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2009/05/mvvm-communication-among-viewmodels.html) to communicate between the viewmodels. OR

[MVVM Mediator Pattern](http://sachabarber.net/?p=477)

Comment: -1 for not reading my question about mediator... Mediator is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Mediator is not a anti-pattern. Refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern#Known_anti-patterns.